# The General Solution of Lipschitz Constant for Matrix-Valued Matrix Function

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, matrix-norms

Define $F: \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{p\times q} $,assuming F is differentiable，What is the general solution for the lipschitz constant L that satisfies $\| F(B)-F(A) \| \leq L \|B-A\|$? $\|\cdot\|$ is induced matrix norm .  Is it also related to partial derivatives ((i.e. $\| \frac{ \partial vec(F(X))}{\partial (vecX)^T} \|$ ) like Jacobian matrix to vector-valued function?

Comment: Because a Lipschitz constant $L$ only needs to satisfy an inequality, "solving" for the constant $L$ is a little ambiguous.  If $L$ gives a satisfactory upper bound,  so will any larger (positive) constant.  Also the assumption that $F$ is differentiable could be clarified, as there are $mn$ components of the arguments of $F$.  Did this Question arise in connection with an application?  Providing the context might better motivate Readers to respond in a way you will find useful.

Comment: @hardmath -Thanks for your comment.
L is the minimum value that satisfies the above inequality.
The form of the partial derivative of F is $\| \frac{ \partial vec(F(X))}{\partial (vecX)^T} \|$.
Since L of a vector-valued function is the maximum norm of its Jacobian matrix, I would like to know if there is also such a conclusion for matrix-valued functions, regardless of the specific form of the function.